# Add object to array with jq

Tags: bash, jq

I'm working on a project which manages multiple machines and their Username and IP are stored in a JSON array.

```json
{
  "a.b.c.d" : {
    "visible" : true,
    "color" : "rgb(0, 255, 192)",
    "user" : "ubuntu", #Optional
    "address" : "a.b.c.d",
    "label" : "VPS-Box" #Optional
  },
  "a.b.c.d" : {
    "visible" : true,
    "color" : "rgb(125, 255, 0)",
    "address" : "a.b.c.d"
  }
}
```

I have a very basic API which only needs one thing and that's to listen for the client application to send its pub IP over telnet in my case the listener is netcat

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true; do

    nc -l -p 1337 >> #here it needs to insert the data in to the json array

done
```

I have gone through many ways to do it using awk, sek, echo nothing works the way I want it to

```json
"nc value" : {
    "visible" : true,
    "color" : "rgb(0, 253, 255)",
    "user" : "REDACTED",
    "address" : "nc value",
```

How should I do this in a way that doesn't corrupt the entire JSON and make the application unusable? My last try below

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    received_data=$(nc -l -p 1337 | tr -d ' ')  # Remove spaces from received data
    echo "$received_data" >> /nc-log.txt # just to see if its correctly received

    # Check if the received data is a valid IP address
    if [[ $received_data =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        # Construct the JSON entry
        new_entry="{\"visible\": true, \"color\": \"rgb(0, 253, 255)\", \"user\": \"REDACTED\", \"address\": \"$received_data\"}"

        # Add the new entry to Machines.json
        jq ". += {\"$received_data\": $new_entry}" /Machines.json > tmp.json && mv tmp.json /Machines.json
    fi
done
```

Comment: How exactly is the JSON being corrupted? The code example creates the expected output (although you should probably be using `--arg` to pass in variables e.g. `jq --arg IP "$ip" '. + {($IP): {visible: true, color: "rgv(0, 253, 255)", user: "REDACTED", address: $IP}}'`)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot take this question seriously with the wrong names. You're working on an object, not an array. Make it make sense... adding to an array and adding to an object are _completely_ different kinds of operations. You should correct that first of all, and also, show the full results of the `nc` command. You're probably over complicating your approach that could probably be done more succinctly with a single command.